# Outlier Treatment and Forecasting

Tags: forecasting, outliers

I have come across multiple methods regarding outlier treatment:

*(features = my input/regressor/... matrix)*

1. Treat outliers in the entire sample (both features and the variable to be forecasted).
2. Treat outliers in the feature sample, leave the variable to be forecasted untreated.
3. Treat outliers in the entire sample that is used to fit the model. When forecasting, use untreated feature values.

What is the correct way? I have thought about it and to me it seems to be a philosophical question rather than a mathematical (in a narrow sense) one. Is there right or wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean by "treat"? What is your task? Do you want to clean up data before learning a regression?

Comment: Perhaps you mean "treatment" as to apply a dummy variable for that observation? Also, try to check if the extreme values goes for only one feature, many features, the forecast variable or all the above.

Comment: By "treat" I mean something like winsorizing/truncating.